# Gettting element from combobox problem in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to get the selected element from combobox in tkinter. I will use this selected element in my code. There are some asked questions and posts in internet but they did not help me. So, I am sharing the related part of my code :

```
     self.dugme2 = Button(text="printer", command=self.ekle, fg="black", bg="green", font="bold")
     self.dugme2.place(relx=0.40,rely=0.65)

     self.ip_list2 = ttk.Combobox(width=15,state="readonly")
     self.ip_list2["values"] = ["eth0", "wan0","wan1"]
     self.ip_list2.place(relx=0.60, rely=0.08)
     self.ip_list2.set("Interfaces")
     self.selected_interf=self.ip_list2.get()
```

In the foregoing code, I tried to get the selected element using `self.selected_interf=self.ip_list2.get()`. After that, I wanted to print it in the screen using button and following function by

```
   def ekle(self):
     self.etiket3 = Label(text=self.selected_interf, font="Times 11 bold", bg="grey")
     self.etiket3.place(rely=0.78, relx=0.39)
```

**I want to print the selected element in the combobox on the label when i click on the button**

Can you help, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `self.selected_interf=self.ip_list2.get()` inside `ekle()` instead.  Also it is better to create label `self.etiket3` once and update its text inside `ekle()`:

```py
        self.dugme2 = Button(text="printer", command=self.ekle, fg="black", bg="green", font="bold")
        self.dugme2.place(relx=0.40, rely=0.65)

        self.ip_list2 = ttk.Combobox(width=15, state="readonly")
        self.ip_list2["values"] = ["eth0", "wan0", "wan1"]
        self.ip_list2.place(relx=0.60, rely=0.08)
        self.ip_list2.set("Interfaces")

        # create the label here instead of inside `ekle()`
        # initially it is hidden
        self.etiket3 = Label(font="Times 11 bold", bg="grey")
```

```py
    def ekle(self):
        # get selection of combobox here
        self.selected_interf = self.ip_list2.get()
        # update label and show it
        self.etiket3.config(text=self.selected_interf)
        self.etiket3.place(rely=0.78, relx=0.39)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code as follows

```
self.dugme2 = Button(text="printer", command=self.ekle, fg="black", bg="green", font="bold")
self.dugme2.place(relx=0.40,rely=0.65)

self.ip_list2 = ttk.Combobox(width=15,state="readonly")
self.ip_list2["values"] = ["eth0", "wan0","wan1"]
self.ip_list2.place(relx=0.60, rely=0.08)
self.ip_list2.set("Interfaces")

def ekle(self):
 self.selected_interf=self.ip_list2.get()
 self.etiket3 = Label(text=self.selected_interf, font="Times 11 bold", bg="grey")
 self.etiket3.place(rely=0.78, relx=0.39)
```